# how should i track changes in datatable record using jsf?

Tags: jsf

Suppose i have an editable table ,which means that i could add/update values to a single record. and this table brings about 20 records from Database.

as i said before i could add or update a single record , so i need to send this only changed record to database to be processed/saved not all the 20 records.

so my question is how to keep track of the changed/modified record back to the database to alert the Database to process only this changed  records?

is this can be done using jsf Datatable feature? using (richfaces -myfaces - icefaces - primfaces - etc--)

thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't the responsibility of JSF. It's just a component based MVC framework for form based applications (i.e. it's merely front-end matter). You should reframe the question in Java perspective (along with JDBC and/or JPA, depending on how you're interacting with the DB by Java). Once you got the answer, just use/invoke exactly that Java code in a JSF managed bean class in combination with some JSF push/poll component.

Comment: Thanks MR. BalusC for ur Answer,

i know i could do this using JDBC OR JPA , but i was wondering if there is any feature like (Some sort of Listener) in datatable component to detect which record has been changed/ deleted and submit these changed records (only changed records/deleted) to the DB , So i won't need to submit the whole datatable again to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

JSF dont have that functionality and icefaces too. I'm not sure about others. You can achieve by the following steps

1. Have a edit button in your table row
2. Once edit button is pressed allow user to update content
3. when submit you can easily capture how many rows are edited, persist only edited rows

**See this:** [Primefaces DataTable - InCell Editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf)

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. it was really helpful. and yes i found the  Primefaces DataTable - InCell Editing. But my boss Doesn't want that one. he needs an editable row without any edit button. and any change happens in any of the rows. can be detetcted and these changed rows only will be Sent to the DB. but Anyway thanks for ur efforts